# Uncommon present continuous verbs

Tags: word-choice, word-request, verbs, present-continuous

Today, I learned that some verbs can be used in present continuous form to make statements and requests sound less direct.

> *I'm asking permission to be excused from work  for at least three days.*

> *Some of the groups are wanting to possibly make some changes.*

I have seen this usage of wanting  for first time. Can you please tell some other verbs which are uncommon in present continuous form and can be used to make statements and requests less direct?

To be honest, I cannot understand how it makes the statement less direct (in the second example).

Comment: I personally consider the second sentence to be sloppy at best. There's no need to be less direct. Do they want to make changes or not? The first sentence works fine if you're telling a third party that you are in fact currently asking permission. But if the sentence is directed at the person you're asking permission from, it's better (again, in my opinion) to _ask_. As a question. May I be excused?

Comment: You can say tentatively "I was hoping that..." meaning that you would like something to happen but are not sure whether it is possible or whether the person will be willing to help.